# Combine like columns within a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
    A         B       C
Superman Laser eyes

Flash    Super speed

Hulk     Green

Superman Flight
```

I would like to combine these rows, for instance:

```
    A         B       C
Superman Laser eyes Flight

Flash    Super speed

Hulk     Green
```

But none of the solutions I've tried so far have worked, is there a quick/simple way to do this in python?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

if you're on >= python3.6 this should work

```
import csv

heroes = {}
with open('a.csv', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if len(row) > 1:
            heroes.setdefault(row[0],[]).extend(row[1:])


heroes_list = []
for key, val in heroes.items():
    heroes_list.append([key] + val)

with open('b.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(heroes_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the issue is I'm getting 'list index out of range' when I try this code.

Comment: guess you have lines without a property in there ?
update should check that

Comment: I guess I do. @lwohlhart How would I go about removing those lines?

Comment: the updated version should check before accessing such values.
I do however also really like the solution from @papke, similar to mine but somehow more elegant with the dictionary holding the final lists directly. Give this one a try maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
import csv
dic = {}
#read csv
with open('input.csv', "r") as f: 
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        #populate dictionary of lists
        if row[0] not in dic:
            dic[row[0]] = row
        else:
            dic[row[0]]+= row[1:]
rows = list(dic.values())
#write csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
    csv.writer(g).writerows(rows)

#output:
A,B,C
Superman,Laser,eyes,Flight
Flash,Super,speed
Hulk,Green
```